# Meanings of signs - ER Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

What is the meaning of `#`, `*`, and `o` for an Entity Relationship Diagram?

I guess `#` is primary key, what about others?

```
Are there any other signs that are not shown here?
```

[image]

Comment: With what tool are you creating your ER diagrams?

Comment: I am creating my diagrams with MySQL Workbench but this sample from my instructor's course materials.

Comment: A little web searching found this: http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~bernatja/crowsfoot.html.  It suggests the asterisks indicate identifiers, so I'm guessing the `#` is an internal key to a person (name + lastname).  However, you should probably ask your instructor for a reference.  I don't think there is a "standard" for symbols like this; they are dependent on the tool used to create the ERD (and I don't think those are in MySQL Workbench).